# If S is a nonempty set, then $F^S$ is a vector space over F

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given a task to prove the following statement

> If $S$ is a nonempty set, then $F^S$ is a vector space over $F$ .

Definitions:

> If $S$ is a set, then $F^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $F$.

I was trying to construct a proof, but do not even know where to start. Could you please suggest me any idea how can I prove this statement ?

I will try to construct proof based on the advices in the comments:
There are 2 operations on $F^N$:
addition $F^S : (f + g) (x) = f(x) + g(x)$
multiplication $F^S : (zf) (x) = zf(x)$

In order for a set V to be a vector space operations of addition and multiplication should be defined ( we already have it ) and following properties should held:
associativity
commutativity
distributivity
additive inverse
additive identity

Comment: Note that for $\lambda,\mu\in F$ and $f,g\in F^S$ we define $\lambda f+\mu g$ as $\big(\lambda f+\mu g\big)(s):=\lambda f(s)+\mu g(s)$ for all $s\in S$.

Comment: What's the definition of a vector space? Once you went through the definition, try to identify what the addition and multiplication on $F^S$ could possibly be. Then just go through every part in the definition to verify every part. By the way, $S$ doesn't even need to be non-empty for $F^S$ to be a vector space, but that's just an interesting side fact to note.

Comment: addition on $F^S : (f + g) (x) = f(x) + g(x)$

Comment: multipllication on $F^S : (zf) (x) = zf(x)$

Comment: I'm assuming here that the letter $F$ is supposed to suggest that $F$ is in fact a **field**, yes?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, correct.

Comment: Then the right thing to do is to edit the question to include that fact, not make potential answerers look through all the comments to discover it. You can edit by clicking "edit" just below your question.

Comment: $S$ doesn’t need to be nonempty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You only need to verify the vector space axioms. For example, you need to show that $F^S$ is an abelian group with the sum of vectors. This sum is defined as follows: Given two vectors $f,g\in F^S$ i,e, $f,g:S\rightarrow F$, define $(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)$ for every $s\in S$ (remember that $F$ must be a field). Note that this sum satisfy  $f+g=g+f$, because for every $s\in S$ $(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)=g(s)+f(s)=(g+f)(s)$ and in $F$ the sum is also conmutative. In the same way you can proof the other axioms of abelian group. The axioms realted with scalars are also easy to check, you only need to use the right definition of product between scalars and vectors.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $f(s)+g(s)=g(s)+f(s)$ ?

Comment: 1st and 3rd equalities by definition of addition in the vector space; 2nd equality be commutativity of addition in the field $F$.

Comment: @RustemSadykov $f(s),g(s)\in F$ and $F$ is a field, so the sum must be conmutative. Then the equality in the midle follows. The other equalities are just definitions.